# How to add optional $stateParams using AngularJs ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to add optional `$stateParams` to below `$state` ,Lets say currently i have `processId` and i want to add `assessmentId` as optional `params`. My goal is to launch same template and controller from two places in application and it will launch based on `$stateParams`.

How can i achieve that task ?
app.js

Add Challenge

```
.state('app.addPrcChallenge', {
            url: '/add/prcChallenge',
            params: { processId: null,assessmentId:null},
            templateUrl: 'views/process/processChallenge.html',
            controller: 'ProcessChallengesCtrl',
            data: {
                authenticate: true
            },
            resolve: {
             existingChallenge: function(){
                    return null;
              },
```

Edit Challenge

```
.state('app.editPrcChallenge', {
            url: '/edit/prcChallenge/:challengeKey/processId?/:assessmentId?',
            templateUrl: 'views/process/processChallenge.html',
            controller: 'ProcessChallengesCtrl',
            data: {
                authenticate: true
            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly mention them in the url with a `?` suffix for optional params:

```
.state('app.addPrcChallenge', {
   url: '/add/prcChallenge/:processId/:assessmentId?',
   templateUrl: 'views/process/processChallenge.html',
   controller: 'ProcessChallengesCtrl',
   data: {
     authenticate: true
   },
   resolve: {
     existingChallenge: function(){
        return null;
     }
   }
});
```

You can ignore the `params` property after this change, as the `params` property is used to define params which do not appear as part of the URL

Comment: How about edit screen there i need three `params` where two params will be optional I added edit `$state` to question.

Comment: Because you missed the `:` before it

Answer (score 0):

You URL property should be like this:

```
.state('app.addPrcChallenge', {
            url: '/add/prcChallenge/:processId/:assessmentId?',
            templateUrl: 'views/process/processChallenge.html',
            controller: 'ProcessChallengesCtrl',
            data: {
                authenticate: true
            },
            resolve: {
             existingChallenge: function(){
                    return null;
              },
```

Comment: if i am specifying params in url , do i still need `params:{processId:null,assessmentId:null}` ?

Comment: Then you won't need that, it provides the default value of the params

Comment: I edited & added ? to the first param, which means it is optional

Comment: The answer you have mentioned is wrong, because it does not have `?` after `assessmentId`

Comment: Ok. I see that you have edited it but this still is wrong because you are making `processId` as optional, while the requirement is for `assessmentId` to be optional. See my answer above

Comment: @hussain As for your question, the params property is used to define params which do not appear as part of the URL. I have mentioned it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
.state('app.addPrcChallenge', {
   url: '/add/prcChallenge/:processId/:assessmentId',
   templateUrl: 'views/process/processChallenge.html',
   controller: 'ProcessChallengesCtrl',
   params: {
     processId: null,
     assessmentId: null
   }
   data: {
     authenticate: true
   },
   resolve: {
     existingChallenge: function(){
        return null;
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: Please, provide more details like why you chose this approach and why your code works.